# Why does my vector::erase call throw "vector subscript out of range"?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that saves words from a .txt file in vector `words`, calculates how many words are there (num_elements) and prints these words randomly to the screen (no duplicates).

It all works fine up until `rw.erase` line, which just spits out the error "vector subscript out of range".

Why is my `erase` call throwing "vector subscript out of range"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void path_to_main_dir() {
    string path = "C:/Randomizer/";
    for (const auto& entry : experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
        cout << entry.path() << endl;
    }

}

int main() {

    path_to_main_dir();
    string dateread;
    printf("Which file do you want to open? ");
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    path_to_main_dir();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "User: ";
    getline(cin, dateread);
    string path_to_file = "C:/Randomizer/" + dateread + ".txt";
    ifstream readfile(path_to_file.c_str());
    vector<string> words;
    string word;
    while (getline(readfile, word))
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    readfile.close();
    srand(time(NULL));

    string randomword;
    vector<string> rw = { words };
    int num_elements = size(words);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of words in the file: ";
    cout << num_elements;
    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < num_elements; a = a + 1)
    {
        randomword = rw[rand() % num_elements];
        cout << randomword << endl;
        rw.erase(remove(rw.begin(), rw.end(), randomword), rw.end());
        num_elements -= 1;
        system("pause");
    }

    goto firstline;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How do I fix this?" - By not accessing elements that are outside of the range your `vector` holds, of course.

Comment: I know, but I don´t see my mistake, that´s why I´m asking.

Comment: please provide a [mre], presumably `r` is more than `rw.size()`

Comment: @Rabbit: Too many of these variables are undefined to be able to see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: How should we help you if you show only half of the variables used? What are `words`, `size` and `r`? From first glance `rand() % r` probably should be `rand() % rw.size()`?

Comment: To erase a single element from the vector, use `rw.erase(iterator)` not `rw.erase(iterator, rw.end())`.

Comment: That's exactly why you narrow it down to a [mcve]. You'll probably work out the problem yourself that way. Good luck

Comment: So guys, as requested I posted the code.

Comment: `r` is still undefined. Anyway, std::remove will remove **all** instances of the found word, but you reduce the value `num_elements` only by one. dont use the temporary variable `num_elements` but `rw.size()`.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to change it, it should be "num_elements".

Comment: `rand() % words` does not make sense! You mean `words.size()`? Also I don't know the purpose of the for loop... try debugging your program...

Comment: I just edited it second before you posted the comment, it should be "num_elements" :3

Comment: The idea of the for loop is that it prints random words from a .txt file as many times as there are words. So e.g. 3 words in a file, it would print those words in a random order.When I debug it, without the remove  and num_element -1 line, it does its job it prints 5 random words from a file that contains 5 words. The problem is that it prints soe words 2x or 3x times (duplicates).

Comment: Not exactly, I want to print out these 5 words that are in the file. Lets say the wods are: one, two, three, four and five. When I run the program, it looks something like this: one, two, two, five, four. And I want it to just print the words in a random order.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b00bc6f7d030f9f8

Comment: BTW a better algorithm would be to randomly sort the vector, print it, then clear it

Answer (score 0):

If the error only happens in the case where there are duplicates, it could be because the num_elements is wrong. The `remove`/`erase` call will have deleted as many duplicates as there are, but num_elements has only been reduced by one.

Fortunatly, vectors know their own size, so rather than trying to remember its internal information for it, you can just ask!

```
int main()
{
    //...
    //Code to read words from file
    //...

    cout << "Number of words in file: " << words.size() << endl;

    while(!words.empty())
    {
        string randomWord = words[rand() % words.size()];
        cout << randomWord << endl;
        words.erase(remove(words.begin(), words.end(), randomWord), words.end());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*From what I can see, you only use `words` to create `rw`, so we could just use `words` directly instead.*

Comment: _Given we transformed the whole vector, this now point to the end iterator of the vector._ No. That's not how `remove` works. It returns the iterator of where the new end **would** be if it actually removed anything. But `remove` does not remove, it moves. Therefore, assuming the word actually existed (which it must have), it will not return `rw.end()`. Also, your final code has undefined (at least unknown to anyone) behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, apparently I just completely misunderstood how `remove` worked. I've removed this part of the answer. What was the undefined behaviour you had spotted?

Comment: Yes, since you would then be accessing values which had been "moved". So I don't necessarily know if its undefined, but it's potentially problematic. The function `remove` really bothers me, since it doesn't actually _remove_ anything.